# Retinal 11-cis-retinal to all-trans induced by photons

Tags: organic-chemistry

In the reaction involving conversion of 11-cis-retinal to all-transform, why does the isomerization specifically occur at the 11th carbon in the molecule? When reforming the broken pi-bond, why wouldn't it happen at the cis-conformation again? Is this due to the trans-form being more stable in this case and that it has a lower enthalpy?
[image: Reaction]

Comment: Yes, probably, all such changes are governed by that. From what I could gather, there's likely a steric issue there. It would help if you add an image of the reaction, including all the conditions.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Ok, I just added an image!

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73289/isnt-11-trans-retinal-more-stable-than-11-cis-retinal https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64219/when-is-rotation-around-double-bonds-to-form-cis-trans-isomers-allowed https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107505/what-is-thermal-isomerization

Answer (score 2):

There are more steps than the net reaction scheme posted by the OP. The trans-isomerization goes along with hydrolysis of a Schiff base, releasing the molecule from opsin. Several enzymes then recycle the 11-cis-retinal before it forms a Schiff base again with opsin, ready for the next light-induced isomerization to the trans form. Here is an overview from a [2010 review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2891588/) (doi: 10.1016/j.tibs.2010.01.005):

[image]

The isomerization from the all-trans to the 11-cis form (step iv) is catalyzed by the [RPE65 enzyme](https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1212025109) containing an iron(II) center via a carbocation intermediate. The details are not yet clear (no well-resolved structures of the substrate or product complex), but the presence of an enzyme can help to isomerize a specific double bond rather than obtaining a product mixture. Also, by coupling unfavorable reactions with favorable ones, you can get a molecule that is kinetically trapped in a high-energy state, ready to undergo isomerization (step i) as a way to detect light.

The "why 11-cis" question is addressed in this [computational paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja208789h): "The results show that the electrostatic interaction between retinal and opsin dominates the natural selection of 11-cis-retinal over other cis isomers in the dark state."